# Configure two network interfaces on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, internet, network-manager

My computer is running Ubuntu Server 14.04, and is connected to two networks at the same time (i.e., local network A with IP 192.168.1.30, which has access to Internet; and another local network B with IP 10.73.9.30, which does not have an Internet access). Most traffic should go through network A, however, I also need my computer to communicate with other computers in the network B (e.g., 10.84.1.8 -- yes, actually not in the same subnet of network B). I have set `metric` in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file so that I can set two gateways, but it seems that only the first gateway works, and computers in other subnet of network B (i.e., 10.84.1.8) cannot access my computer (10.73.9.30) at all.

Interestingly, computers in the same subnet of network B (e.g., 10.73.9.3) can access my computer without any problem, and 10.84.1.8 can also access 10.73.9.3 (which is only connected to network B). Therefore, I think the cause of the network issues on my computer is that it is connected to two networks. Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto em1
iface em1 inet static
metric 0
address 192.168.1.30
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1

auto em2
iface em2 inet static
metric 1
address 10.73.9.30
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.73.9.1
```

How can I make the computer use 10.73.9.1 as the default gateway for `10\.*\.*\.*` IP addresses?

Comment: There cannot be two default gateways for the same host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a route to 10.0.0.0/8:

`route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.73.9.1 dev em2` (untested)

To make it permanent add it to your interfaces config in the em2 section:

`up route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.73.9.1 dev em2`

Just for understanding: Your computer knows where to send packets in your local net. For everything else, he needs routes. The default route is used if there isn't a more specific route. Now you have told him to send all packets for that subnet over a different router, that probably knows where to send the packets. (or knows who else might know.)

Comment: Wow... it works! Thanks so much! Just wondering whether I need to do it again after rebooting? Which file has this new route be written to? @Jakob Lenfers

Comment: I updated my answer with information about that.